# Finding Highest , Lowest and the Average in a Cobol program

Tags: file, input, output, cobol, highest

I am creating a program that is reading in a file which consists of companies and their information. It is supposed to read all the records in my file then display the companies with a 3.5 rating or higher with their information, then it is to reject companies with a rating lower that 3.5 and then display the highest quote and the lowest quote and then the average among the companies. I am new to Cobol so I am not sure how to find the highest, lowest and the average. I have coded what I though would work in Module 2012 to find the highest but when I run my program it does not display the information. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. MOVING-QUOTES.



   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

       SELECT MOVING-QUOTES-FILE ASSIGN TO 'Moving-Quotes.txt'
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
       SELECT MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-FILE ASSIGN TO "MOVING.TXT"
            ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL. 

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
   01 FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD             PIC X(45).

   FD MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-FILE.
   01 MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD        PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2).
       05 MQR-COMPANY-NAME                 PIC X(15).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(1).
       05 MQR-COMPANY-PHONE                PIC X(13).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(1).
       05 MQR-MOVING-QUOTE                 PIC 999V99.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(1).
       05 MQR-NUMBER-ITEMS                 PIC 999.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(1).
       05 MQR-RATING                       PIC 9V9.

   01 PRT-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2).
       05 PRT-MQR-COMPANY-NAME             PIC X(15).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05 PRT-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE            PIC X(13).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(5).
       05 PRT-MQR-MOVING-QUOTE             PIC $zz99.99.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(7).
       05 PRT-MQR-NUMBER-ITEMS             PIC 9(3).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(15).
       05 PRT-MQR-RATING                   PIC 9.9. 

   01 PAGE-TITLE.
       05                  PIC X(22) VALUE SPACES.
       05                  PIC X(40) VALUE  'MOVING COMPANY QUOTES'.
       05                  PIC X(18) VALUE SPACES.
       05 PRT-PAGE-NUM     PIC Z9.

   01 QUOTE-HEADING-1.
       05                               PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                               PIC X(7)  VALUE 'COMPANY'.
       05                               PIC X(9) VALUE SPACES.
       05                               PIC X(5)  VALUE 'PHONE'.
       05                               PIC X(21) VALUE SPACES.
       05                               PIC X(9)  VALUE 'NUMBER OF'.
       05                               PIC X(11) VALUE SPACES.
       05                               PIC X(4)  VALUE 'YELP'.
       05                               PIC X(7). 

   01 QUOTE-HEADING-2.
       05                                  PIC X(8).
       05                                  PIC X(4)  VALUE 'NAME'. 
       05                                  PIC X(11) VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(6)  VALUE 'NUMBER'.
       05                                  PIC X(9)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(5)  VALUE 'QUOTE'.
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(5)  VALUE 'ITEMS'.
       05                                  PIC X(13) VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(6)  VALUE 'RATING'.
       05                                  PIC X(2)  VALUE SPACES.
   01 QUOTE-HEADING-3.          
       05                                  PIC X(6)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(9)  VALUE  ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(8)  VALUE  ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE  ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(11) VALUE  ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(7)  VALUE SPACES.
       05                                  PIC X(8)  VALUE  ALL '-'.



   01 WS-SWITCHES-AND-COUNTERS.
       05 WS-EOF                         PIC X       VALUE 'F'.
       05 NUMBER-OF-PAGES                PIC S9(4)   COMP  VALUE 0.
       05 NUMBER-OF-LINES-USED           PIC S9(4)   COMP VALUE 0.
       05 WS-HI-BID                      PIC 999V99 VALUE 0.
       05 WS-LO-BID                      PIC 999V99 VALUE 999.99. 
       05 WS-TOTAL-BID-SUM               PIC 999V99 VALUE 0. 
       05 WS-NUMBER-OF-RECORDS           PIC 9(4)    VALUE 4.
       05 WS-AVERAGE                     PIC 999V99. 

   01 HI-COMPANY-INFO.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
       05 SAV-HI-MQR-COMPANY-NAME          PIC X(15).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES.
       05 SAV-HI-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE         PIC X(13).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES.
       05 SAV-HI-MQR-QUOTE                 PIC $ZZ99.99.

   01 LO-COMPANY-INFO.
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(5) VALUE SPACES. 
       05 SAV-LO-MQR-COMPANY-NAME          PIC X(15).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES.
       05 SAV-LO-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE         PIC X(13).
       05 FILLER                           PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES. 
       05 SAV-LO-MQR-QUOTE                 PIC $ZZ99.99.

   01 AVG-INFO.
       05                                  PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
       05 SAV-AVG                          PIC $ZZ99.99. 

   01 HI-INFO-HD1. 
       05                                  PIC X(8).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE 'HIGH'.
       05                                  PIC X(8).
       05                                  PIC X(5) VALUE 'PHONE'.
       05                                  PIC X(52).

   01 HI-INFO-HD2.
       05                                  PIC X(6).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE 'COMPANY'.
       05                                  PIC X(10).
       05                                  PIC X(6) VALUE 'NUMBER'.
       05                                  PIC X(9).
       05                                  PIC X(5) VALUE 'QUOTE'.
       05                                  PIC X(37).
   01 HI-INFO-HD3.
       05                                  PIC X(5).
       05                                  PIC X(9) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(8).
       05                                  PIC X(8) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(36).

   01 LO-INFO-HD1. 
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05                                  PIC X(3) VALUE 'LOW'.
       05                                  PIC X(13).
       05                                  PIC X(5) VALUE 'PHONE'.
       05                                  PIC X(52). 

   01 LO-INFO-HD2.
       05                                  PIC X(6).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE 'COMPANY'.
       05                                  PIC X(10).
       05                                  PIC X(6) VALUE 'NUMBER'.
       05                                  PIC X(9).
       05                                  PIC X(5) VALUE 'QUOTE'.
       05                                  PIC X(37). 

   01 LO-INFO-HD3.
       05                                  PIC X(5).
       05                                  PIC X(9) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(8).
       05                                  PIC X(8) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(36).

   01 AVG-INFO-HD1.
       05                                  PIC X(7).
       05                                  PIC X(7) VALUE 'AVERAGE'.

   01 AVG-INFO-HD2.                       
       05                                  PIC X(6).
       05                                  PIC X(9) VALUE ALL '-'.
       05                                  PIC X(65).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   0000-MAINLINE.
       PERFORM 1000-START-MOVING-QUOTES
       PERFORM 2000-READ-N-PRINT-MQ
            UNTIL WS-EOF = 'T'    
       PERFORM 3000-FINISH-UP
       STOP RUN
       .


  *END OF MAIN BLOCK 

   1000-START-MOVING-QUOTES.
       OPEN INPUT MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
            OUTPUT MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-FILE
       PERFORM 8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       IF WS-EOF NOT = 'T' 
           PERFORM 8020-PRINT-TITLE-AND-HEADINGS.
       .


   8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
       READ MOVING-QUOTES-FILE 
           AT END MOVE 'T' TO WS-EOF
       end-READ
       MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO 
            WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD 
       .        


   8010-CHECK-LINES.
       ADD 2 TO NUMBER-OF-LINES-USED
       IF NUMBER-OF-LINES-USED > 90 
           PERFORM 8020-PRINT-TITLE-AND-HEADINGS
       .

   8020-PRINT-TITLE-AND-HEADINGS.
       ADD 1 TO NUMBER-OF-PAGES
       MOVE NUMBER-OF-PAGES TO PRT-PAGE-NUM
       MOVE SPACES TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       MOVE PAGE-TITLE TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD 
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD AFTER ADVANCING 3 LINES
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM NUMBER-OF-PAGES
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE          
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM QUOTE-HEADING-1
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM QUOTE-HEADING-2
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM QUOTE-HEADING-3 
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       .

   8025-PRINT-HI-HD.
       MOVE SPACES TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM HI-INFO-HD1
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE 
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM HI-INFO-HD2
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM HI-INFO-HD3 
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       .

   8026-PRINT-LO-HD.
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM LO-INFO-HD1
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE 
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM LO-INFO-HD2
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE 
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM LO-INFO-HD3
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       .

   8027-PRINT-AVG-HD.
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM AVG-INFO-HD1
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE 
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD FROM AVG-INFO-HD2
           AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       . 


   2000-READ-N-PRINT-MQ.
  *  PERFORM 8010-CHECK-LINES
       PERFORM 8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       IF (MQR-RATING >= 3.5) 
           MOVE WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO 
           PRT-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
           PERFORM 2001-PRINT-COMP
           PERFORM 2010-FIND-HI-LO-AVG
       END-IF   


       .

   2001-PRINT-COMP.
       MOVE MQR-COMPANY-NAME TO PRT-MQR-COMPANY-NAME
       MOVE MQR-COMPANY-PHONE TO PRT-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE 
       MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO PRT-MQR-MOVING-QUOTE 
       MOVE MQR-NUMBER-ITEMS TO PRT-MQR-NUMBER-ITEMS 
       MOVE MQR-RATING TO PRT-MQR-RATING 
       MOVE PRT-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD 
           AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
       ADD 1 TO WS-NUMBER-OF-RECORDS  
       .

   2010-FIND-HI-LO-AVG.

       PERFORM 2012-FIND-HI
       PERFORM 2013-STORING-VAL-LO
       PERFORM 2014-FIND-LO
       PERFORM 2015-GET-SUM

       PERFORM 2016-GET-AVERAGE
  *     PERFORM 8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       .

   2011-STORING-VAL-HI.
       MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO WS-HI-BID
       . 

   2012-FIND-HI.
       PERFORM 2011-STORING-VAL-HI   
       IF (MQR-MOVING-QUOTE > WS-HI-BID)
           MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO WS-HI-BID
           MOVE MQR-COMPANY-NAME TO SAV-HI-MQR-COMPANY-NAME
           MOVE MQR-COMPANY-PHONE TO SAV-HI-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE 
           MOVE WS-HI-BID TO SAV-HI-MQR-QUOTE
           MOVE HI-COMPANY-INFO TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
           WRITE MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD 
               AFTER ADVANCING 2 LINES
       END-IF
       .               

   2013-STORING-VAL-LO. 
       MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO WS-LO-BID
       .       

   2014-FIND-LO. 
       IF (MQR-MOVING-QUOTE < WS-LO-BID) 
       MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO WS-LO-BID
       MOVE MQR-COMPANY-NAME TO SAV-LO-MQR-COMPANY-NAME
       MOVE MQR-COMPANY-PHONE TO SAV-LO-MQR-COMPANY-PHONE 
       MOVE MQR-MOVING-QUOTE TO SAV-LO-MQR-QUOTE
       .       

   2015-GET-SUM. 
       ADD MQR-MOVING-QUOTE GIVING WS-TOTAL-BID-SUM
       .

   2016-GET-AVERAGE.
       DIVIDE WS-TOTAL-BID-SUM BY WS-NUMBER-OF-RECORDS  GIVING
              WS-AVERAGE
       MOVE WS-AVERAGE TO SAV-AVG
       .


   3000-FINISH-UP.

       PERFORM 8025-PRINT-HI-HD
       PERFORM 2012-FIND-HI
       PERFORM 3010-PRT-HI
       PERFORM 8026-PRINT-LO-HD
       PERFORM 2014-FIND-LO
       PERFORM 3020-PRT-LO
       PERFORM 8027-PRINT-AVG-HD
       PERFORM 2016-GET-AVERAGE
       PERFORM 3030-PRT-AVG


       CLOSE MOVING-QUOTES-FILE 
             MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-FILE
       .

   3010-PRT-HI.
       MOVE HI-COMPANY-INFO TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       . 

   3020-PRT-LO.
       MOVE LO-COMPANY-INFO TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       .

   3030-PRT-AVG.
       MOVE SAV-AVG TO MOVING-QUOTES-RESULTS-RECORD
       .
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34745741/1927206. If using conditions (`AT END`) you should use a scope-terminator (`END-READ` in this case). A full-stop/period is a super-scope-terminator and should be avoided like the plague. Only use full-stoprs/periods where they are needed. Prior to the 1985 Standard, they were required everywhere outside conditions. They terminated conditions. These days they still have the same power, but the errant full-stop/period has caused so many problems throughout COBOL's lifespan that many argue against their use.

Answer (score 3):

@Magoo is quite correct, you have not ended the Read so the following lines
are **only** executed at the end-of-file

```
   MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO
        WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD.
```

another option is the end-read

```
8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
   READ MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       AT END MOVE 'T' TO WS-EOF
   end-Read
   MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO
        WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD
   .
```

personally I would move the "Move FS-MOVING" to 2000- or 8010-

```
2000-READ-N-PRINT-MQ.
     MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO
          WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD
     PERFORM 8010-CHECK-LINES

     ....
8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
   READ MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       AT END MOVE 'T' TO WS-EOF
   end-Read
   .
```

---

One final point, when you number procedures they should put them in numeric sequence

---

Some more issues in 2000- the perform 8000- should be at the end of the procedure

Currently:

```
  2000-READ-N-PRINT-MQ.
  *  PERFORM 8010-CHECK-LINES
       PERFORM 8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
       IF (MQR-RATING >= 3.5) 
           MOVE WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO 
           PRT-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
           PERFORM 2001-PRINT-COMP
           PERFORM 2010-FIND-HI-LO-AVG
       END-IF
```

Should be:

```
  2000-READ-N-PRINT-MQ.
  *  PERFORM 8010-CHECK-LINES
       IF (MQR-RATING >= 3.5) 
           MOVE WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO 
           PRT-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
           PERFORM 2001-PRINT-COMP
           PERFORM 2010-FIND-HI-LO-AVG
       END-IF   
       PERFORM 8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
```

also in 2012- why are you doing a write, surely this should be done at the end (section 3000-).

Comment: See my update; also what is the input ?? what is the output ?? what have you done to work out what the problem is ??? You could put in displays to see what is happening (or use a debugger

Answer (score 2):

```
8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
       READ MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
           AT END MOVE 'T' TO WS-EOF
           not AT END
       MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO
            WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD.
```

I loathe this syntax. Give me a bag of full stops any day.

```
8000-READ-MOVING-QUOTES-FILE.
       READ MOVING-QUOTES-FILE
           AT END MOVE 'T' TO WS-EOF.
       MOVE FS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD TO
            WS-MOVING-QUOTES-RECORD.
```